# Link native items in my HTML project?

Tags: html, native

I have build an webapplication. And now i would like a link to the navigation function (like maps). This is a native feature of the mobile or tablet, so how do i link it in an HTML project? Is it even possible?

Comment: You want a link to open specific apps on a mobile device? Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

On an iPhone you can create a link to Maps by following [Apples URL Scheme Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/MapLinks.html) for this.

There they state:

> Native application URL string [for maps]:
>   `http://maps.google.com/maps?q=cupertino`

Which you  can mark up as:

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=cupertino">Cupertino</a>
```